# I did this Python script that was supposed to automatically shoot squares in a web games called diep.io . It is not working, what did I do wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pywin32, pyautogui

This is the code. Comments are for sizes and the shapes RGB code. Might be an error with variables. I tried many times to fix but it did 0 changes. Note that I am a beginner.

````
#Square RGB 255 232 105
#Pentagon 118 141 252
#Extreme screen top left 230 130
#Extreme screen bottom right 1250 630
#Extreme screen bottom left 230 630
#Extreme screen top right 1250 130
#Screen size 1365 767
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
                           

while keyboard.is_pressed('l') == False:
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region(230, 130, 1020, 500))
    width, height = pic.size
    for x in range(0, width, 5):
        for y in range(0, height, 5):
            r, g, b = pic.getpixel((x, y))
    if g == 232:
        click(x+230, y+130)```
````

Comment: Can you describe how it's not working?

Comment: Yes, It does not affect the gameplay at all. It was supposed to automatically detect and click anything that had green value for 232. It just does nothing. I can play chill while the program is running.